# SWIG: How to handle proprietary conventions such as __declspec(dllimport) in interface file?

Tags: c++, swig

I got a syntax error while processing my interface .i file using SWIG:

```
MY_Workspace> swig -C++ -python cpp_dll.i

cpp_dll.h(10) : Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

Below are interface file and C++ header file:

interface file:

```
%module SimpleClass_dll

%{
#include “cpp_dll.h"
%}

%include "windows.i"
%include "cpp_dll.h"
```

Header file: cpp_dll.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef API_IMPLEMENT
#define DLL_API _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLL_API SimpleClass
{
public:
    SimpleClass();
    ~SimpleClass();

    int     Add(const int x, const int y);
    int     Sub(const int x, const int y);

    int     GetBufSize();
    char    *GetBufAddr();

private:
    char    *m_buf;
    int     m_bufsize;
};
```

I've read through the chapter "windows" in swig manual so i added "windows.i" in my interface file. But still, the error occurred.  Adding "windows.i" looks worked for [Bernardo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294655/does-a-function-type-extern-declspecdllimport-int-cdecl-makes-sense-in-c). I really need your help to figure out why it's not work for me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried removing parts of the code in cpp_dll.h to identify, where the error is? I think it may be related to DLL_API / _declspec. Try to remove that and see what happens.

Comment: It's `__declspec` (two underscores).  You are correct that you need `windows.i` to correctly handle `__declspec`, but it has to be written correctly :^)

Comment: @Mark， like you've pointed out, putting an extra leading underscore fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Eduard, thanks for your input and have a nice day!